# .tail() not working properly on SeriesGroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am currently trying to get the last n-elements of a pandas Series and convert them to a list.
my current code is:

```
genomes = df[["generation_index", "serialized_multineat_genome"]].groupby(by="generation_index")[
                       "serialized_multineat_genome"]
genomes_lst = genomes.tail(100).to_list()
```

The pandas df has a shape of (40000,x) with the resulting Series being (40000,). I want to get the last 100 elements of which using `.tail(100)` however when looking at `genomes.tail(100).shape` it is still of shape (40000,).

EDIT:
The the series consists of strings, grouped by their generational index `range(0,400)` with each generation consisting of 100 individuals. I want to get the 100 last individuals.

EDIT 2:
The simplest solution was to restructure the query. Since I was trying to get the individuals of the last generation the easier way is to do it as follows:

```
genomes = df["serialized_multineat_genome"].loc[df["generation_index"] == df["generation_index"].max()].tolist()
```

Comment: I would be better for clarity to provide a small example (like I did in my answer) and the matching expected output. I just want to make sure I interpreted the question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As you want to generate a list per group, use a custom function in [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html)/[`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
genomes.agg(lambda g: g.tail(100).tolist())
```

Or, for a list of lists:

```
genomes.agg(lambda g: g.tail(100).tolist()).tolist()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('AABBBBCDDDDDD'), 'values': range(13)})

N = 3
df.groupby('group')['values'].agg(lambda g: g.tail(N).tolist())

group
A          [0, 1]
B       [3, 4, 5]  # kept last N values
C             [6]
D    [10, 11, 12]  # kept last N values
Name: values, dtype: object

df.groupby('group')['values'].agg(lambda g: g.tail(N).tolist()).tolist()

[[0, 1], [3, 4, 5], [6], [10, 11, 12]]
```